# Jquery change location then scroll to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I am on the index.php and press the home button, it scroll down to the element. However, when I'm not on the index.php and press the same button, I want to change the URL location, then scroll to the element. This is how I tried:

```
$('.home').on('click', function (event) {

    // If location is index.php do this:
    if (location.href.indexOf("/index.php") > -1) {

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#anotherelement").offset().top
        }, 1000);

        // If location is not index.php do this:
    } else {
        window.location = "index.php";

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#anotherelement").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

It just changes the url but it doesn't scroll to element when I'm not on the index.php

Comment: you need to use it (the scroll effect) on dom ready function

Comment: when you change location you are loading a new page so your code of scrolling is useless since you are doing it from the "previous" page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hash instead of using jQuery to scroll to some element.

1. Add the hash to the URL `http://www.myurl.com/index.php#anotherelement`
2. Add the element with the same id(`anotherelement` in this example) in the page where you want to scroll on page load.

Comment: Ya that's correct but then there isn't any animation. This could be handled using `hashchange` event on the new loaded page but apparently that fits OP needs anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to

```
$('.home').on('click', function (event) {
    if (location.href.indexOf("/index.php") > -1) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#anotherelement").offset().top
        }, 1000);

    } else {
        window.location = "index.php#anotherelement";
    }
});
```