# How to focus on a particular portion of an another html page when click on a button or link

Tags: javascript, html

first i want to redirect to another page then it has to focus but first it is focusing and after that it is redirecting to another page (dynamically i am getting href values i dont want to change that)? suggest me the ideas how to achieve this

```
<a href="httP://..." onclick="focusOnPage()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 function focusOnPage()
 {
   var papers=document.getElementById('someid');
   papers.style.Display='';
   papers.scrollIntoView();
 }
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32944399/2025923

Comment: in redirected page its not working tushar sir

Comment: You've to pass `#myId` in the URL, the id of the element where the page should scroll

Comment: $('.Focus').on('click', function (event) {
             debugger;
             if (location.href.indexOf("http://localhost:6424/Website13/") > -1) {
                 $('html, body').animate({
                     scrollTop: $("#<%=divPapers.ClientID %>").offset().top
                 }, 1000);

             } else {
                 window.location = "#http://localhost:6424/Website13/";

                 $('html, body').animate({
                     scrollTop: $("#<%=divPapers.ClientID %>").offset().top
                 }, 1000);
             }
         });  my code

Answer (score 1):

2 Notes.

1. The `onclick` function firing before the `href` redirect the user. (You can prevent the `href` redirect in `onclick` function.
2. If you want to focus the element **after** the redirect so your function `focusOnPage` should not occur when the user **clicked** on the link, but after the new page loaded after the redirect.

Something like this:

```js
function scrollToFocus() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#needToFocus').offset().top
  }, 1000);
}

$(window).load(scrollToFocus);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Title 1</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, debitis maiestatis eu duo, dolores epicurei verterem cu per. Has ea intellegat elaboraret, te legendos invenire postulant nec. An legimus assentior disputando pri. Ei omnis vulputate pertinacia nam. Ex eos errem electram omittantur,
eu ipsum mazim petentium qui, pri saepe congue id. Pri quas lobortis ut. Solum denique eu mea, ex viris incorrupte scriptorem vel. Vix ne mucius mollis, no saperet molestiae nec. Ut aliquid efficiantur vim, an sed primis oporteat. Eos simul omnes at.
Eum quod primis docendi te, sumo laudem melius te sea. In has elaboraret persequeris. Et amet insolens contentiones vel, his ignota indoctum ex, idque saepe et pro. Tation explicari accusamus eam ad, no cum nonumy cetero nonumes. Vel consetetur repudiandae
ei. Quo semper facilisi ne, quod delenit repudiandae duo ad. Regione fabulas signiferumque te quo, sed elitr numquam id. Pro diceret civibus blandit ei. Impetus euismod id cum, ea sea unum nullam intellegebat. Ex dolorum utroque eam, vide laboramus persecuti
an cum. Ut sea saperet concludaturque, audire sapientem sea ut. Alii dicat placerat vim ut, vel te diceret expetenda liberavisse. Has nisl justo sensibus ut. Per an graece honestatis, deleniti maluisset necessitatibus an cum. Ex suas dicat nobis nec,
ea vis melius argumentum repudiandae.


<h2>Title 2</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, debitis maiestatis eu duo, dolores epicurei verterem cu per. Has ea intellegat elaboraret, te legendos invenire postulant nec. An legimus assentior disputando pri. Ei omnis vulputate pertinacia nam. Ex eos errem electram omittantur,
eu ipsum mazim petentium qui, pri saepe congue id. Pri quas lobortis ut. Solum denique eu mea, ex viris incorrupte scriptorem vel. Vix ne mucius mollis, no saperet molestiae nec. Ut aliquid efficiantur vim, an sed primis oporteat. Eos simul omnes at.
Eum quod primis docendi te, sumo laudem melius te sea. In has elaboraret persequeris. Et amet insolens contentiones vel, his ignota indoctum ex, idque saepe et pro. Tation explicari accusamus eam ad, no cum nonumy cetero nonumes. Vel consetetur repudiandae
ei. Quo semper facilisi ne, quod delenit repudiandae duo ad. Regione fabulas signiferumque te quo, sed elitr numquam id. Pro diceret civibus blandit ei. Impetus euismod id cum, ea sea unum nullam intellegebat. Ex dolorum utroque eam, vide laboramus persecuti
an cum. Ut sea saperet concludaturque, audire sapientem sea ut. Alii dicat placerat vim ut, vel te diceret expetenda liberavisse. Has nisl justo sensibus ut. Per an graece honestatis, deleniti maluisset necessitatibus an cum. Ex suas dicat nobis nec,
ea vis melius argumentum repudiandae.

<h2 id="needToFocus">Title 3</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, debitis maiestatis eu duo, dolores epicurei verterem cu per. Has ea intellegat elaboraret, te legendos invenire postulant nec. An legimus assentior disputando pri. Ei omnis vulputate pertinacia nam. Ex eos errem electram omittantur,
eu ipsum mazim petentium qui, pri saepe congue id. Pri quas lobortis ut. Solum denique eu mea, ex viris incorrupte scriptorem vel. Vix ne mucius mollis, no saperet molestiae nec. Ut aliquid efficiantur vim, an sed primis oporteat. Eos simul omnes at.
Eum quod primis docendi te, sumo laudem melius te sea. In has elaboraret persequeris. Et amet insolens contentiones vel, his ignota indoctum ex, idque saepe et pro. Tation explicari accusamus eam ad, no cum nonumy cetero nonumes. Vel consetetur repudiandae
ei. Quo semper facilisi ne, quod delenit repudiandae duo ad. Regione fabulas signiferumque te quo, sed elitr numquam id. Pro diceret civibus blandit ei. Impetus euismod id cum, ea sea unum nullam intellegebat. Ex dolorum utroque eam, vide laboramus persecuti
an cum. Ut sea saperet concludaturque, audire sapientem sea ut. Alii dicat placerat vim ut, vel te diceret expetenda liberavisse. Has nisl justo sensibus ut. Per an graece honestatis, deleniti maluisset necessitatibus an cum. Ex suas dicat nobis nec,
ea vis melius argumentum repudiandae.
```