# How to scroll to certain element inside the list after the redirect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, anchor

I'd like to ask any idea behind the concept of redirecting from notifications into the specific url and then scroll to a certain content like comments and others. Look, what I'm trying to get here is I have a notification icon above which has a dropdown list containing a link to a specific url. So, I want to scroll to certain element here after the redirect and in this it's a list of comments which are bounded via knockout. So far, all I can do is only to scroll to a certain element which  is a link that has an anchor `<a name="newcomment"> </a>` after the page has loaded with the use of this simple redirect code `window.location = "/MyController/MyActionMethod#newcomment";`. I want to scroll it to a specific element which in this case the **`<div id="commentdiv" >`** element which holds a certain comment. Here's the HTML layout below which holds comment in a certain URL. Any idea? Thanks.

```
 <a name="newcomment"> </a><br />

  <ul id="commentlist" style="list-style:none;float:left">
                    @*Loop comments here*@
       <li data-bind="foreach: commentinfo">
             <div id="commentdiv" >       
              <img id="commentorpic" data-bind="attr:{src: '/ProfilePhotos/' + ProfilePhoto}" src="#"/>            
              <label id="commentorname" class="commentorname" data-bind="text: UserName" >  </label><br />
              <label id="elapsedtime" data-bind="text: DateNTime"></label> <br />
               <p id="userscomment" class="userscomment" data-bind="text: Comments"></p>                    
                        <br />
              </div>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Use **hash** in the URL, and id to the element

Comment: How? Do I need to create a jquery function on this?

Comment: No, Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32944399/2025923

Comment: I this is the same as what I did already which is window.location = "/MyController/MyActionMethod#newcomment"; but I want to scroll it inside the loop which is the div element named <div id="commentdiv" > that holds a certain comment.

Comment: Did you read that answer? It's mentioned that you need to add the id to the element where you want to scroll. and same id should be passed as hash in the URL

Comment: I tried something like what you said which is window.location = "/MyController/MyActionMethod#commentdiv"; but it's not going anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery.scrollTo() function to scroll to your specific element. If the element of known on the server, then you must be to register a script similar to the following:

```
$(body).scrollTo('#commentDiv');
```

Comment: Ok this one,take note that I'm scrolling to a list of comments which is more that one comment. So are you sure that it will scroll to a specific comment. Let's say I have 30 comments and I need to scroll in the middle like 14th comment or the 20th comment. I think this will just scroll on the first comment but I'll try this.

Comment: It will work provided you give the ID of the relevant comment. If you want to scroll to the 10th comment, then use the ID (selector) of the 10th comment.

Comment: Well, I guess my problem is to get the exact id of that element which holds the specific comment because it is within the loop of foreach. I want to make the same comment section capability like the stackoverflow.com just the same right now we are commenting and you'll get notified and then will redirect you to the exact comment on top.

Comment: Please tell us that you have not assigned the same id to multiple comment DIV elements. If you want to scroll to div with id "commentdiv10" just put `#commentdiv10` as a hash value in the URL. A quick look at how SO does it suggests all comments have unique ids and a link to a comment involves a server redirect.